# An Unhandled Execution Error on opening oracle connection

Tags: c#, oracle, wcf, oracle11g

I'm using oracle ODP.Net library but I'm getting an Unhandled Execution Error at the cnn.open(); line without even one word in it's "message" property.
the most important point is that, this problem exists in my WCF project an not elsewhere.

```
Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection cnn =
     new Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection("Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521)) (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=orcl)));User Id=masoud;Password=123;");

cnn.Open();
```

more detail:

> **Description:** An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> **Exception Details:** Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException:
>
> **Stack Trace:** 
>   [OracleException (0x80004005)]
>      Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleErrorHelper(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, String procedure, Boolean bCheck, Int32 isRecoverable) +1336
>      Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleError(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, Object src) +70
>      Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.Open() +8141
>      Fig.TradingSystem.Services.App_Code.Bootstrapper.AppInitialize() in d:\App_Code\Bootstrapper.cs:29
>
> [TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
>      System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) +0
>      System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) +192
>      System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) +108
>      System.Web.Compilation.BuildResultMainCodeAssembly.CallAppInitializeMethod() +146
>      System.Web.Compilation.CodeDirectoryCompiler.CallAppInitializeMethod() +27
>      System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallAppInitializeMethod() +36
>      System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +530
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
>      System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9913572
>      System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +101
>      System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +254

What do you think?

Comment: does your wcf service run in an IIS AppPool. And if yes, does this special user has the permisscion to connect to this resource...?

Comment: no bro,whole of project is in development environment yet and as you know visual studio host WCF in **IIS Exress**.

Comment: also I use exactly this connection string  in another project type (Class libraries and Console application) and there is no problem.

Comment: you can see in the stacktrace, it still has to do with your http config, see innerexception '[HttpException (0x80004005): Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.] System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9913572 '

Comment: but even with "SYSTEM" user id I've faced with this exception :( still you think permissions cause this problem?

Comment: I've test this connection string with **System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection** created by Microsoft Corporation and there was no problem, but unfortunately I have to use ODP.Net because I need it's bulk copy class.

Comment: even "Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection" open connection without any problem....I'm going to cry :'(

Comment: I'm not sure about permissions. What the stacktrace shows is it needs an existing HttpContext. As you call this outside of a webrequest, the HttpContext does not exist! Can you delay the call to the database using a Lazy<SomeClass>?

Comment: **Update1**
During I was investigating this problem,I de-installed the odp.net library and installed again the problem was solved, the connection opened well but this happiness didn't take much and this annoying exception appeared again without any clear reason for me.